# React Native Wrong LAN IP Hosting Fix

Tags: react-native, expo

Whenever I run

> npm start (react-native-scripts start)

It hosts the Application on the endpoint of **192.168.1.200:19000**

The issue is my Windows computer has the IP address of **192.168.0.31**

*Is there a way to change this React Native hosting IP address so it is hosting on the correct IP?*

The application does not start etc. The only way to run this expo app and have it connect is through the tunnel (which is 70% slower when refreshing the app etc).

Side note: This bug does not happen on my mac OS computer, Only on my Windows 10 computer development machine I am trying to transfer to.

**Edit:** Is there a way to always have this be my computer's router assigned IP address? I'm confused why this breaks for RN on windows vs RN on mac.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below question thread.

It answers your query.

[React Native Expo change default LAN IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696813/react-native-expo-change-default-lan-ip)

Hope it helps.