# I have an error on expo: something went error

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an error with a blue screen when I execute `expo start`, it says:

> something went wrong. could not load exp://169.254.12.63:19000.Networkresponse time out

There is also a link that says:

> view error log" and there say: "uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeOutExeption:connect timed out

This is my `App.js`

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

I want to emulate this app on genymotion.

Comment: Is the ip address correct?

Comment: Make sure that is the correct ip of your desktop and check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696813/react-native-expo-change-default-lan-ip

Comment: hi, it say that i must set the enviroment variables with set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME="my ip adress" but already i did it and still doesn't work, i set this variable on cmd

Comment: After setting that environment variable, re-run your react native command and check whether the IP address is correct.