# Expo- Could not connect to the server

Tags: react-native, expo

i trying to open a new project in my iphone , and it shows this message:[image]

NOTE: the connection is LAN , on TUNNEL mode it works fine but slow

Answer (score 2):

You tried to connect to the wrong IP.
the 127.0.0.1 is a localhost IP.
You have to change to the IP where your Metro Builder Server runs on.

Maybe this Thread helps you to change to the correct IP:
[React Native Expo change default LAN IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696813/react-native-expo-change-default-lan-ip)

Comment: I executed this command as he say 'set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=my ip' , but nothing change except of the ip number on the screen, another idea?

Comment: Is your metro builder server running? Maybe you can provide us the log output of the server?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Start > Control Panel > System
2. Go to Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
3. Set a System Environment Variable with the following name/value pair:
4. name: REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME
5. value: < the IPv4 address you want to use > (if any address does not work, enter the current address IPV4 you are using)

That’s it!

IMPORTANT: remember to close and re-open the elevated PowerShell command prompt, since newly added Environment Variables wont’ be available on the existing prompts.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue because my VPN was running on my Android device. Switching it off worked for me

Answer (score -2):

- Change to LAN connection type in expo-cli
- Open it again from your phone
- If you get a similar error but with your LAN IP, your network does not allow connections between devices on the network, and you need to use tunnel or use simulator with localhost.

Comment: Hi, can you be a little more specific please?