# Scanning Error Expo: Network response time out

Tags: react-native, expo

When the QR code on the dashboard of my laptop is scanned by the Scanner of Expo in my Android, it shows the `error "Something went wrong Network response time out"`.

And when I open error log file, it shows `"Uncaught  Error: Java. net. SocketTimeoutExpection"`.

What should I do it?

Comment: the QR code you scanned is for your app or for expo snack ?

Comment: It's only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your local IP address that is running EXPO and look at the IP Address that EXPO is running on - these should match minus the port.

So for example, if your local machine has an IP of 192.168.0.210, EXPO should be Opening exp://192.168.0.210:19000. If they differ, you must change the EXPO environment variable for the IP address. Refer to [React Native Expo change default LAN IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696813/react-native-expo-change-default-lan-ip) for that

Comment: So sorry for late reply. Firstly, I wanna thank you for your help. After fixing, my local mechine's IP and EXPO's IP address are the same. But, another error shows like this "Uncaught Error: java.net.ConnectException". What should I do? Thank u.