# How to get Wifi IP address from Expo when debugging on USB?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, ip

To detect the IP address our server is running on, I use the following code:

```
const localhostIP = Constants.linkingUri.split(':')[1].replace('//', '');
```

This works for testing via Wifi connections. It returns the Wifi address of my laptop.

However, when debugging on USB, I use:

```
npx expo start --localhost --android
```

Now this line of code returns `127.0.0.1` as address and I cannot use it as server address. The server runs on my laptop and needs to be called from its LAN IP address.

How do I retrieve the LAN IP address of my laptop from JavaScript using Expo and React Native?

**I tried using the following packages:**

`react-native-network-info` -> returns `null`
`expo-network` -> returns `0.0.0.0`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696813/react-native-expo-change-default-lan-ip

Comment: @James I didn't want to manually enter the IP Adress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by grabbing the IP Address from the console and adding it to an environmental variable

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/